# got bad header error in wget on beaglebone black

Tags: linux, wget, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I am running

```
wget --output-document=/tmp/1.jpg "http://ip_address/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=888888"
```

on the beaglebone black, and it give me the following error:

```
wget: bad header line: tue, 12 Jun 2012 01:56:34 GMT
```

This command works perfectly on other linux environments except my beaglebone black.

I don't know what happens here. Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are actually using wget and not the "BusyBox" version of wget that comes with the default angstrom distro.

```
opkg update
opkg install wget
```

Now try and see if wget works as you would expect it to. I had problems with wget too untill i realised that it is a stripped down version of wget.